# ACCESS_VIOLATION when use Hook Engine

Tags: c++, sockets, hook

I have a problem using this hook engine http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21414/Powerful-x86-x64-Mini-Hook-Engine

Function is hooked correctly, but when i try to call real function(original), error ACCESS_VIOLATION is raising.

My code

```
typedef int (__stdcall *MyCloseSocket) (SOCKET s);
MyCloseSocket pTrampolineCloseSocket = NULL;

    int main()
    {
     //...
      HookFunction((ULONG_PTR) GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary(dll), "closesocket"),  (ULONG_PTR) &OwnCloseSocket); 
      pTrampolineCloseSocket = (MyCloseSocket) GetOriginalFunction((ULONG_PTR) OwnCloseSocket);
    }

int OwnCloseSocket(SOCKET fd)
{
        // here successfully. Function is hooked
    return pTrampolineCloseSocket(fd); // but here ACCESS_VIOLATION
}
```

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @TJD `SOCKET` is `SOCKET`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Have you considered writing an LSP instead? It's a bit more versatile than what you are trying with hooking.

Answer (score 2):

If you are free to choose the technology for hooking I recommend our own hooking engine Deviare because it handles the hooking complexity itself (remote process injection, parameters parsing, race conditions) giving a higher level programming interface. It is available at http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/ hope it will speed up you solution

Comment: This is on topic. I think that when you have a solution it is important to give it here. We are very proud of our technology and know how valuable it is.

Comment: I didn't doubt it was on-topic. But since this is a commercial offering it would be good if you were honest about your affiliation. For example the link I gave is a free-of-charge alternative by someone else :)

Comment: I am being honest. I said: "I recommend OUR OWN hooking engine Deviare...". And you can use it freely, just an image appear when the COM/.NET object is instantiated and then it fade off. The commercial version doesn't have this image.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the implementation of the rest of your program, you have a potential race condition where your hook function could be called before `pTrampolineCloseSocket` is set. What's the value of `pTrampolineCloseSocket` when you crash?